# exception when incoming message modified for a method with "not blank" Uri template

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.0

I get the following exception when i modify the incoming Message for a web service method with URItemplate which is not blank.

System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

So it works for

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/")]
```

and

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "/")]
```

but NOT

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "/id")]
```

and NOT

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/id ")]
```

Below is how i modify the message.(I sort the xml nodes in alphabetical order)

```
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {


            //get the request as xml
            string xml = request.ToString();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(xml))
            {
                //create a new xml document
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(xml);

                XElement xmlElement = XElement.Load(new XmlNodeReader(doc));
                XDocument sortedXml = new XDocument();
                XElement root = new XElement(xmlElement.Name);
                sortedXml.Add(root);

                Sort2(xmlElement, root);

                request = Message.CreateMessage(request.Version, null, new SimpleMessageBody(sortedXml.ToString()));
            }
            return null;
        }


 public class SimpleMessageBody : BodyWriter
    {
        string xmlContent;

        public SimpleMessageBody(string content)
            : base(true)
        {
            this.xmlContent = content;
        }

        protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
        {
            using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlContent))
            {
                using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlTextReader.Create(stringReader))
                {
                    writer.WriteNode(xmlReader, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I read the following in REstful.net

> "You can use Message as a parameter
>   only if it was the only parameter to
>   an operation"

So what are my options..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed

```
 request = Message.CreateMessage(request.Version, null, new SimpleMessageBody(sortedXml.ToString()));
            }
```

to

```
Message newMessage = null;
                newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(request.Version, null, new SimpleMessageBody(sortedXml.ToString()));

                newMessage.Headers.CopyHeadersFrom(request);
                newMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(request.Properties);
                request = newMessage;
```

Comment: Thanks. I had a similar problem and your solution helped resolve my issue. I use Carlos Figueira's [Raw programming model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/03/01/supporting-raw-requests-for-individual-operations.aspx) code to also support Raw streams. In a non-raw request that contains parameters, copying the original headers (assumed Raw) to the copy (XML or JSON) is necessary to preserve them and avoid the IndexOutOfRangeException bug in WCF. But I didn't copy the Properties because they overwrote the WebBodyFormatMessageProperty needed by the default deserializer.